# Separar cadena en columnas, eliminar caracteres especiales de dentro

Tags: python, string, pandas, split, caracteres

Tengo una columna de un df en el que hay medidas por pies y pulgadas separados por sus caracteres especiales correspondientes:

```
df.altura

0        5' 4"
1        5' 11"
2        5' 10"
3        5' 7"
```

y lo que tengo que hacer es crear una nueva columna en la que se encuentre la misma altura pero en centimeros, es decir, multiplicando el primer numero por 0.3048 y el segundo por 0.0254 y sumandolos.
si los separo me sigue quedando el ultimo caracter ahi y luego para sumarlos lo haria haciendo slice, multiplicando y sumando pero para ello tengo que conseguir separarlos sin que queden los quotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes aplicar `str.rstrip` o un simple rebanado para eliminar la `"` final:

```
df.altura.str[:-1].str.split("'", n=1))
df.altura.str.rstrip('"').str.split("'", n=1)
```

No obstante una forma mucho más simple en mi opinión es usar `pandas.Series.str.extract` con la expresión:

```
(\d+)\'\s*(\d+)\"
```

- `\d` -> Clase de caracteres, cualquier dígito.
- `+` -> Cuntificador, 1 o más
- `*` -> Cuantificador, 0 o más
- `()` -> Grupos de captura, cada uno formará una columna nueva.
- `\s` -> Espacio.

La expresión es muy simple y cubre los ejemplos dados, puede adaptarse según necesidades, por ejemplo si cabe la posibilidad de tener decimales o si puede faltar los pies o las pulgadas en alguna fila.

Esto genera directamente un DataFrame con dos columnas, una por grupo de captura. Simplemente lo convertimos a entero, multiplicamos por 0.3048 y por 0.0254 y aplicamos `pandas.DataFrame.sum` sobre las filas:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({"altura": ("5' 4\"", "5' 11\"", "5' 10\"", "5' 7\"")})
df.altura = (df.altura.str.extract(r"(\d+)\'\s*(\d+)\"")
               .astype(int)
               .mul([0.3048,  0.0254])
               .sum(axis=1)
               )
```

> ```
> >>> df
>    altura
> 0  1.6256
> 1  1.8034
> 2  1.7780
> 3  1.7018
> ```

Si como mencionaba, cabe la posibilidad de tener decimales, necesitamos modificar la expresión:

```
import re
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({"altura": ("5.4'  4.3\"", ".5' 11\"", "5'0.10\"", "5'7\"")})
```

> ```
> >>> df
>        altura
> 0  5.4'  4.3"
> 1     .5' 11"
> 2     5'0.10"
> 3        5'7"
> ```

```
PATT = r"""
    ((?=.)(?:[+-]?(?:\d*)(?:\.(?:\d+))?)) # Primer número
    \'                                    # Litaral para '
    \s*                                   # Cero o más espacios intermedios
    ((?=.)(?:[+-]?(?:\d*)(?:\.(?:\d+))?)) # Segundo número
    \"                                    # Literal para "
"""

df.altura = (df.altura.str.extract(PATT, flags=re.VERBOSE)
                          .astype(float)
                          .mul([0.3048,  0.0254])
                          .sum(axis=1)
                          )
```

> ```
> >>> df
>     altura
> 0  1.75514
> 1  0.43180
> 2  1.52654
> 3  1.70180
> ```

---

> **P.D.** La conversión es a metros, para que sea a centímetros debe multiplicarse por `[30.48,  2.54]`.